If an error occurs when using supabase's auth.signinwithpassword, it cannot be caught
function Login() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const supabaseClient = supabase();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const { data: loginData, error } =
        await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithPassword({
          email: data.email,
          password: data.password,
        });

      if (error) throw error;

      const userData = await supabaseClient.auth.getUser();
      const { id } = userData.data.user;

      router.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('loginError', error.message);
      if (error instanceof AuthApiError) {
        if (
          error.status === 400 &&
          error.message === 'Invalid login credentials'
        )
          return;
      }
    }
  };

Hello, I implemented login logic using supabase. The problem is that when i try to log in by entering incorrect user information, an error object is created, which is thrown and passed to the catch block. However, I found that the error was still active through Chrome Developer Tools.

As shown in the picture, both the error.message output to console.log from the catch block and the uncaught error are visible on the console screen. I searched for various solutions through Googling, but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know a solution to this issue?
I tried changing the signIn method, but the same issue still occurs.

What are you referring to here? I can see the console.log in your code to log the error. If you are talking about the POST error, that is a http request response which you have turned on in your console. That isn't anything related to whether you catch the error or now.
